# How can I check to see if an image is onscreen in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anybody know how I can make a program that takes a screenshot and checks if an image appears inside that screenshot?

I've seen similar questions, but they all check where the image is, not if it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/). If you get a position, then it *exists*. If you don't get a position, it *doesn't exist*.

**EDIT:** You can use [this](https://medium.com/@martin.lees/image-recognition-for-automation-with-python-711ac617b4e5) tutorial. [Python-Imagesearch](https://github.com/drov0/python-imagesearch) is actually a wrapper around opencv2, so it should work properly.

Comment: How do I get started with OpenCV?